# How to test if DNS is working over IPv6

Tags: linux, dns, ipv6

My two VPS servers host my DNS. I have it setup to work with both IPv4 and IPv6. I'm able to test IPv4 without a problem. How can I test IPv6?

I tried entering the IPv6 address in digwebinterface.com and it didn't work.

My ISP only offers IPv4 so I can't test from home. Is there an alternative to test IPv6 functionality on my DNS servers for my domain?

Comment: It does not matter if your ISP has only IPv4, you could have full IPv6 by using [Hurricane Electric's tunnelbroker](https://www.tunnelbroker.net/) or [SixXS](https://www.sixxs.net/main/). Think of them as added ISP's.

Comment: Do you mean, test whether DNS traffic runs over IPv6, or do you mean, DNS resolves IPv6 addresses?

Comment: Also, are you trying to test your DNS server as a resolver, or as an authoritative server for your domains?

Comment: I was trying to test if I can resolve IPv6 addresses using OpenDNS and also test if authoritative worked as well. Both do now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try it from your own VPS servers:

```
dig AAAA your.ipv6.host @localhost
```

You can even try resolving the host between the two VPS replacing `@localhost` with the host/IP address of the other server. This way you can even test if there are not firewall related issues.

Answer (score 8):

To test whether DNS resolves over IPv6, you can tell dig to only use IPv6 as transport:

```
dig -6 www.google.com
```

This will use whatever IPv6 DNS server you specified in resolv.conf.

If you want to be sure to test own DNS server:

dig www.google.com @2001:db8::1

(substitute your own IPv6 address, of course)

Answer (score 1):

You can open a command prompt and to the following from your machine:

```
ping -a ENTERHOSTNAME -6
```

This will attempt to ping your machine locally connecting and returning a response using IPv6. Use -4 to test IPv4.

To get your hostname open up a CMD and enter:

```
hostname
```

Comment: This doesn't really test DNS, though, because localhost is usually resolved via /etc/hosts

Comment: @Kevin Keane You can replace localhost with your hostname (machine name) address and use the -6 switch.

Comment: I altered the answer provided so it definitely will work.

Comment: Your change is indeed an improvement, but still not foolproof - your own hostname is sometimes also resolved through /etc/hosts. The other concern is that even if this works, the DNS queries may still run over IPv4 (albeit for IPv6 AAAA records), only the ICMP echo packets would actually travel over IPv6.

Comment: @KevinKeane Very true. For testing purposes you can at least know that your machine can communicate over IPv6. Does my answer truly deserve a -1?